# When uploading an image to state using FilePond in react I keep getting {filename: null, name: "[object Object]"}

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am trying to upload user images using FilePond but when I check my state after using onupdatefiles I get the following error

[State Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4RBR.jpg)

**Before using FilePond I was using a regular input tag with:**

```
<input
   className='upload-img'
   onChange={e => setProfilePic(e.target.files[0])}
   type="file"
   id="img"
   name="img"
   accept="image/*"
/>
```

and that worked fine

Now trying **FilePond Code:**

```
const [profilePic, setProfilePic] = useState(null);

<FilePond
   files={profilePic}
   onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
   setProfilePic({profilePic: fileItems.map((fileItem) =>     
   fileItem.file) })}}

   server={{process: () => {
   let form_data = new FormData();
   form_data.append('profile_pic', profilePic);
   props.updateProfileFiles(form_data}}}

   type="file"
   id="img"
   name="filepond"
   accept="image/*"
   labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>
/>
```

The data is converted in the server property because I am using axios.

Thank You

Comment: From what I can see your `process` method is malformed. It should call `load` see docs. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process-1

Answer (score 0):

kindly Try this

```
onChange={e => setProfilePic(e.target.files)}
```

or use this link for clarification
https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-upload-and-preview-images-in-react-js-4e22a903f3db

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it just times out. I believe that FilePond requires the onupdatefiles property